# Pulling Text From an Event Attribute in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, attributes, onmouseover, attr

I have an anchor with the onmouseover attribute. This event attribute calls another function as so:

```
<a onmouseover="showHint('<h3>some HTML</h3>', this, event)"></a>
```

After getting to the object, is there anyway to pull the HTML from the attribute/function? When I use attr(), it returns the function - but I'd like to grab the string literal.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: whenever you're writing js, especially in jquery, you should avoid writing javascript inline. do it in `$(document).ready()`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like this?

```
var html = "<a onmouseover=\"showHint('<h3>some HTML</h3>', this, event)\"></a>";

var str = String($(html)[0].onmouseover);
//var str = String($("#myLink")[0].onmouseover);

alert(str.split("(")[2].split(")")[0].split(",")[0]);

//Alerts '<h3>some HTML</h3>'
```